# How can I add a .jar file dependencies when building it with the command line tool?

Tags: java, jar

Pretty straightforward question. Can it be done without the use of Ants or Maven? (And by that, I mean the command line tool specifically)

Please notice that I don't want to create an uberjar, I just want the archived unit to "know" where its external dependencies are.

Comment: Reference them to do what?  Create the manifest?  The fact that you're creating the JAR suggests that you've already compiled to .class files.  True?

Comment: My god, that really sounded messy. I'm gonna edit it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming you're talking about a command line invocation of `javac`, what you're talking about is "can I provide libraries as arguments to javac to fulfill requirements during compilation".

Top entry for `man javac` says

> ```
>    -classpath classpath
>           Sets  the user class path, overriding the user class path in the
>           CLASSPATH environment variable.  If neither CLASSPATH or -class-
>           path  is  specified, the user class path consists of the current
>           directory.  See Setting the Class Path for more details.
> ```

Effectively I suspect you just need to say

`javac -classpath path/to/library1.jar Main.java`

Comment: Holy crap, how could I be so stupid? Yeah, you spend a long time using IDE's to make everything for you and forget about the basics. I wasn't compiling the files before adding them to the .jar file (basically, I was archiving a bunch of .java files). Ok, we're done here, thanks.

Comment: Once in a while ditch Eclipse and use `vim` and `mvn`. You'd be surprised how often a straight `mvn package` can highlight stuff that Eclipse hides. Bonus points for adding Hudson (or any other CI) to the  normal practice.

Answer (score 5):

You can make it through `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. You can add other jars to the classpath like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.domain.MyMainClass
Class-Path: lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
```

I believe, that it works only if you define `Main-Class` and start your application like this:

```
java -jar my-app.jar
```

Also notice, that classpath paths are relative to the main jar. So in my example directory structure should look like this:

- my-app.jar
- lib

  - slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
  - slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a manifest file, Look here for more details
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html