# Build jar depending on a lib like org.json without ide

Tags: java, jar

I build a project without any IDE and want to compile it. I dont want to use Maven or Ant. So i have several classes and a jar file (org.json) "json.jar".

```
javac -cp json.jar *.java 
java -cp .;json.jar App
```

Now i want to create another jar file for my project but dont know how to include/link the lib json.jar. I created a manifest.mf

```
Main-Class: App
Class-Path: json.jar
```

and tried

```
jar -cmf manifest.mf App.jar *.class json.jar
```

that creates a jar file but i cant run it. Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "can't run it"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a .jar file dependencies when building it with the command line tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768188/how-can-i-add-a-jar-file-dependencies-when-building-it-with-the-command-line-to)

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher: It just dont open anything. I have created a Swing GUI.

Comment: @Lho Ben: Why you think this is a duplicate? As you can see i have set the classpath..

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher: But when i delete the json.jar file after conmpiling it is not included in the resulting jar file.

Comment: class path in manifest just replaces the class path argument to java command. it doesn't merge any existing jar file into the output jar

Comment: maven has this ability in its [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Comment: So its not possible without using any build tool?

Comment: The 'normal' way is to have the jar dependencies in a location relative to the main jar file, and their relative path specified in the manifest. You don't need (nor should IMO) include all dependent jars inside the main jar.

Answer (score 0):

according to [jar man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/jar/) :

> Be sure that any pre-existing manifest file that you use ends with a
>   new line. The last line of a manifest file will not be parsed if it
>   doesn't end with a new line character.